# Pages Equation Editor - Inserting Equations - Blank Spaces?

Tags: macbook-pro, pages

I am trying to place Mathematical equations in Pages and it appears it doesn't have this feature (why not apple? *glare*), however looking online I was advised to use Equation Editor which I seem to have installed.

Online people are reporting this works fine, but in my document when I copy and paste across I just end up with blank spaces. Does anyone know why?

Thanks for your time,

```
MBP - 10.6.7
Pages - '09 4.04
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure if Equation Editor would work with Pages since it is a Microsoft product and comes with the Office. I might be mistaken but this would seems to be a case of apples and bananas.

On the other hand if you have LaTeX installed in your system and are familiar with it then you might try to use a small and free utility called [LaTexit](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit_en.php). You can check [this explanation](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/08/18/using-latexit-to-display-math-formulas/) to get you started on using equations in Pages.

**An Addition:**
An alternative way to insert equations into Pages would be to use **Grapher** utility which is included in the standard OSX install. Check in your Applications > Utilities to find it. Not only this utility allows you to produce graphs but it also allows you to copy the equation in variety forms (PDF,TIFF, ... LaTeX equation) into your document. The program has quite good "Equation Palette" where you could in principle create your equations to be pasted somewhere else.