# Is there a keyboard shortcut for inserting MathType equations in Pages?

Tags: keyboard, pages

I have more and more thoughts about taking my class notes on my computer, and Pages '09 would seem like a good candidate for that task. However, being that I have a lot of technical classes, I find myself needing to insert MathType equations very often.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to insert such an equation? If not, can I somehow make one?

Comment: You might want to check this question as well: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14431/6303

Comment: @Tigran Khanzadyan, that's quite interesting as I know a fair deal of LaTeX (to the point I've been using MathType as a LaTeX equation parser).

Answer (score 2):

Update for 2019: The newer versions of Pages actually recently added equation support! Just go to Insert > Equation... or hit ⌥⌘E.

It uses LaTeX or MathML, but if you want to use MathType there's apparently a button for that in the resulting dialog, or you can set it to be your default. (I don't have MathType, so I can't test this.)

The [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH26397?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) has more information.

Answer (score 1):

[FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) is my choice to easily make key shortcuts for accessing menu items - much nicer, more flexible and far more powerful than the keyboard preference pane. Also, [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) works wonders for fast switching apps / activating services and learns your preferred key shortcuts on the go rather than having to program them in beforehand (but you can do that too if you like).